# WinForms binding Generic List - checkable business object to a Grid

Tags: winforms, binding, grid

We all like how easy it is to bind with WPF.  Now I am back working with Winforms and I am looking for a nice way to bind my grid to a List of Checkable of BusinessObject (I am sticking with BindingList for Winforms).  So I am essentially just adding a checkable to my business object.

I am using a grid as there will be multiple columns where the user would edit (in this scenario Name and Description on the business object) - as well as adding new objects to the grid and removing from it.  Checked list box does not fit for this purpose as I want to edit columns.

For this I am using .NET 4.

I basically want to reduce the amount of UI code in the scenario so I am using a view model based approach which will populate the list.  I want the user to be able to check a box alongside each of the business object properties.

Sure I can use inheritance, but if I want to apply the same mechanism against a lot of business objects (having lots of different screens where you check items in a list for the different business objects).  Maybe this would be the way to go - but I have my doubts.

Now depending upon the choice of grid - I am using Infragistics - the functionality would hopefully be pretty similar conceptually.

I thought about wrapping the business object up in a Checkable generic class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Checkable<T> : ModelBase
{
    public Checkable(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    private T _value;
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(_value, value))
            {
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _checked;
    public bool Checked
    {
        get { return _checked; }
        set 
        {
            if (_checked != value)
            {
                _checked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Checked");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have made up a business object for this scenario:

```
public class BusinessObject : ModelBase
{
    public BusinessObject()
    {
    }

    public BusinessObject(RepairType repairType)
    {
        _name = repairType.Name;
        _id = repairType.Id;
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set 
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _description;
    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set 
        {
            if (description != value)
            {
                description = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        }
    }

    private int _id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set 
        {
            if (_id != value)
            {
                _id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where ModelBase just implements the INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public abstract class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(field, value)) { return false; }

        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            PropertyChanged = null;
        }
    }
}
```

So potentially for my grid datasource I would define:

```
// in view model
var datasource = new BindingList<Checkable<BusinessObject>>();
... populate list


grid.DataSource = viewmodel.DataSource;
```

So of course my scenario fails at the minute as Value is the BusinessObject reference which has the properties I want to bind to, and Checked is the property for a checkbox which I also want to bind to.

I am trying to kick start the old grey matter with some ideas on this.  I don't really like writing code to define grid columns.  However, the Infragistics grid has been ok for data binding directly to the BusinessObject at design time.  Its possible to add an unbound column (checkbox for my scenario) and handle the checking/unchecking of items manually (which I might potentially have to do).

I am wondering if I am missing any neat tricks with Winform binding of late having missed out with Linq and Entity Framework when they appeared many years ago.

Comment: Solution: Put an `ElementHost` and do it with WPF. winforms is useless.